# Beauty and THE Beast

Tags: articles, definite-article

Please, explain the article usage. Why do you say "Beauty and **the** Beast", "Snow white and **the** seven Dwarfs", but "The Prince and The Pauper"?

Comment: Because *Beauty* and *Snow White* are proper nouns (i.e. names, or at least monikers or appellations) whereas *prince*, *beast*, and *dwarves* are common nouns, or descriptions.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know Beauty is a name!

Comment: @AndreyChechikov "Belle's name means beauty" - http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Belle

Comment: This question isn't necessarily a *learner's* question because although Dan Bron's comment-answer is 100% correct, it isn't immediately obvious from the titles (aside from circular reasoning or familiarity with the stories) that Beauty is the name of the female lead while Prince isn't the name of the male lead of their respective stories.

Comment: Because in the context of the story, there is only ONE beast, ONE group of seven dwarfs etc.

Comment: @DanBron  Hang on a moment there, isn't the beast's name ["Beast"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22beauty+and+the+beast%22+characters+list)? And is Belle (the character's first name) ever called by her moniker/nickname/appellative *Beauty*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Outside the Disney version, her name is often "Beauty". Considering that the title comes from the French origin where the title is, ironically for this question, "*La Belle et la Bête*". Disney likely opted to go with the original French name "Belle" rather than the American transliteration "Beauty". And, technically, (in the Disney version) the Beast's name is "Adam".  This is honestly a very interesting question, considering all of this.

Answer (score 1):

We use the definite article "the" when both the speaker and the listener are familiar with what the noun refers to. We don't need it with proper nouns such as the names Snow White or Beauty because there is only one of them. In the case of "the seven dwarfs" the speaker means the seven dwarfs who live together in the forest where Snow White goes. It is the same with the Beast - this is the particular beast who befriends Beauty. If the title were *Snow White and Seven Dwarfs*, it could refer to any seven dwarfs anywhere, not this group of dwarfs.

Comment: For the most part, speakers use *the* when they assume their addressee(s) can identify the referent. Has little to do with familiarity.